# jquery Form.submit handler not triggered

Tags: jquery, form-submit

trying to use `form.submit(event)` handler to send form data with ajax based on following example.
[jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

But my Handler function does not seem to trigger at all, I have tried adding return false and various prevention of default behavior, but the form still get submitted to action file.

**Javascript:**

```
$('#formWebUI').submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        let form = $(this);
        let url = form.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data)
               {
                   ChangeLocation();
               }
             });
        return false;
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="formWebUI" class="form-inline pb-5" action="/php/form_WebUI.php" method="POST">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3 p-0">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="alias" name="alias" placeholder="Alias">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-7 px-1">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="text" name="text" placeholder="Text">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 p-0">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary w-100" id="formWebUI" value="Add">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

I have also tried the button to be of element button instead of input. Type of the element was always submit never button.
I have tried alerting in javascript, but it seems that the handler is never called no matter what I do. Would be thankful for any advice.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Is the jQuery code inside `$(document).ready`?

Comment: no errors and yes it is inside $(document).ready

Comment: we cannot use duplicate id which you have used ("formWebUI"). so use different id

Answer (score 0):

Your input element shares the same id with the form. Make sure the elements have unique id's, then bind the .submit to the form id.

Wrapping your JQuery in $(document).ready solved the issue for me. See the jsfiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/520x83s7/

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#formWebUI').submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        let form = $(this);
        let url = form.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data)
               {
                   ChangeLocation();
               }
             });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: When an ID is duplicated, the selector will find the first one, so it seems like it should match the form rather than the input.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I made the note about the ID just so he does not miss the duplicate.

Comment: I was desperately experimenting with the id on submit button, but originally it was only on form.

Comment: I really do appreciate such fast response and good will to help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok just found the issue.

The form is loaded asynchronously from other file with Ajax. So when I register the listener it is actually before the form is loaded and can be properly affected.

So to fix I just reinitialize the listener after I load the form from a file.

Comment: See [Event binding on dynamically-created elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)